# Sort array containing DOM elements according to their position in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, dom

## Context

I've structured a jQuery plugin I'm currently working on in a way that has me storing DOM elements in an array, mostly for being able to store more information next to these elements without having to use the not-so-fast `data()`.

That array looks like:

```
[
    { element: DOMElement3, additionalData1: …, additionalData2: … },
    { element: DOMElement1, additionalData1: …, additionalData2: … },
    { element: DOMElement2, additionalData1: …, additionalData2: … },
]
```

The way this plugin works prevents me from pushing these elements to the array in a predictable order, which means `DOMElement3` can in fact find itself at an index lower than `DOMElement2`'s.

However, I need these array elements to be sorted in the same order as the DOM elements they contain appear in the DOM. The previous example array, once sorted, would look like this:

```
[
    { element: DOMElement1, additionalData1: …, additionalData2: … },
    { element: DOMElement2, additionalData1: …, additionalData2: … },
    { element: DOMElement3, additionalData1: …, additionalData2: … },
]
```

This is, of course, if `DOMElement1` appears before `DOMElement2` in the DOM, and `DOMElement2` before `DOMElement3`.

## Discarded solution

The jQuery [`add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) method returns a set of DOM elements in the same order as they appear in the DOM. I could be using this, but the requirement is that I work with a jQuery collection – which means I'd have to refactor a huge chunk of the abovementioned plugin to use a different storage format. That's why I consider this a last-resort solution.

## Another solution?

I would have imagined that [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and a sort of global DOM index tied to each DOM element would have done the trick, but there doesn't appear to be such a "global DOM index".

What approach can you think of? (If writing code, both vanilla JS and jQuery are welcome.)

Comment: I'm curious if you've benchmarked your approach against `data` to see how much faster yours is.

Comment: "The way this plugin works prevents me from pushing these elements to the array in a predictable order" How that? Looks like you should fix that instead

Comment: @JamesMontagne I haven't, but pushing elements to an array *seems* faster than using jQuery's internal cache to attach additional data to each element. I'll create a JSperf to benchmark this right away and post back here.

Comment: @A.Wolff The plugin allows users to add elements to that array whenever they want. Thus, if still using the same example, someone first adds `DOMElement3` to the array, then later `DOMElement1` and `DOMElement2`, the array will look exactly like in the first code sample.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Looks like my approach is indeed faster than using `data()`, at least in the following test case: http://jsperf.com/storing-data-next-to-dom-elements

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a very useful function called [`compareDocumentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.compareDocumentPosition), which returns a number based on where two elements are relative to each other. You can use this in a `.sort` callback:

```
yourArray.sort(function(a,b) {
    if( a === b) return 0;
    if( !a.compareDocumentPosition) {
        // support for IE8 and below
        return a.sourceIndex - b.sourceIndex;
    }
    if( a.compareDocumentPosition(b) & 2) {
        // b comes before a
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
});
```

Comment: *That's* what was tickling my hindbrain. Normative reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-compareDocumentPosition (I love, though, how it utterly fails to say clearly what the return values are.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Fair point, easy enough to add in, will do that now.

Comment: Sadly, IE8 remains a significant in-the-wild browser, and doesn't have `compareDocumentPosition`. You have to use `contains`. More in [this post from John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/comparing-document-position/).

Comment: @A.Wolff: How expensive is all that wrapping and looking up?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ya sure it is. Just checked link you provided, better for sure

Comment: Great discussion, thanks for all these links. IE8 support not being an option here, I'll have to use Resig's snippet to make it work in all major browsers. I've also come up with another vanilla-ish solution, and am on my way to writing a perf comparison between these 3 solutions. Will post here once done.

Comment: I've tested all three solutions mentioned above, and yours if by far the fastest (even with that few elements in the document), so that's the one I'll be using – thanks! You should update your answer to make the link to Resig's post (or the snippet) more prominent for compatibility purposes.

Comment: Here are the three solutions I've tested, in their respective fiddles: [compareDocumentPosition](http://jsfiddle.net/P4b2E/1/) (@NiettheDarkAbsol's answer), [remapping with expando](http://jsfiddle.net/LgWq8/1/) (@T.J.Crowder's answer), and [document.all indexes](http://jsfiddle.net/MxRHE/1/) (another try I gave that problem). Finally, here's the jsPerf comparing all three: http://jsperf.com/sort-array-containing-dom-elements-according

Comment: -throws hands in the air- I win! By a landslide! Woo!

Comment: @user1728278: I suggest editing Niet's answer with the full code required, since you had to work around IE8's lack of `compareDocumentPosition`. Or actually, Niet, probably that should be you. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've just edited with the relevant part of the function - the entire polyfill is not necessary.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Nifty! But...Why not? What is it that Resig's using `compare` for that we don't have to here?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Because we're only interested in whether the `2` bit is set or not (as shown in the `& 2` in my code), we only need that particular check from Resig's code. Resig's code also handles all the other bits, which in this case is unnecessary work.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Cool. I wasn't entirely sure the information about containment wasn't important. If anyone has any doubts, try this on IE8: http://jsbin.com/wahofuja/1 Looks good!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do a lot of refactoring to take advantage of jQuery's sorting. You can use it as a temporary sorting mechanism. Here's an off-the-cuff:

```
function putInDocumentOrder(a) {
      var elements;

    // Get elements in order and remember the index of
    // the entry in `a`
    elements = $().add(a.map(function(entry, index){
        entry.element.__index = index;
        return entry.element;
    }));

    // Build array of entries in element order
    a = elements.map(function(){
        return a[this.__index];
    }).get();

    return a;
}
```

It requires an expando, but it does the job. [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/foduvafo/2)

This has the advantage that it works on all browsers that jQuery supports, rather than your having to deal with the edge cases (IE8 not supporting `compareDocumentPosition`, for instance) yourself.

Comment: Are you sure about that last statement?  I don't believe passing an array of dom elements to the jquery constructor will order them in dom order.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: You were looking at an old page. :-) I was sure that was true, then thought ... I'd better test that ... so I removed it while I was testing, and just now edited again to say no, that isn't true.

Comment: This solution works with [`add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/): `$("div").add([DOMElement3, DOMElement2, DOMElement1])` will give the following jQuery collection: `[DOMElement1, DOMElement2, DOMElement3]`. However, I don't see how this is different from the "discarded solution" I've written about.

Comment: @user1728278: You said that you want to work with an array, not a jQuery collection. The difference is that you end up with an array, not a jQuery collection, by using `get()` in the end.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is true. The other requirement being that, as the code samples suggest, the array doesn't contain DOM element, but objects containing DOM elements (among other things); sorry if I didn't make that clear enough. I'm afraid this solution does not work when the array's members aren't simply DOM elements.

Comment: @user1728278: Ah, okay. I have a thought about that, one sec.

Comment: @user1728278 In the end you might end up needing some sort of map between a sorted collection and a cache of data.  That was kind of the idea behind my first question of if you had benchmarked it.  If in the end you have to completely recreate the functionality of `data`, you should probably just use `data`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the update, it definitely fits the bill. I'll compare your solution performance-wise to @niet's one. (As a side note, afaik, jQuery's `data()` also works with one expando per element to keep a reference to the cache location, pretty much like you're doing; sometimes you just have to use these :-) )

Comment: @JamesMontagne True that, a mapping of some sort will be needed if I can only sort these using jQuery

Comment: @user1728278: :-) Just beware of `compareDocumentPosition` if you need to support IE8, which doesn't have it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've accepted the `compareDocumentPosition` answer, knowing that I'll be using the snippet you provided in your own comment on that answer (so thanks a lot!). Have a look at my last comments on that answer to see how the solution you gave above compares to the others.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't suggest you go with this approach, it is possible with jquery to get a "global DOM index":

```
var $all = $("*");

// use index to get your element's index within the entire DOM
$all.index($YOUR_EL);
```

Comment: Haha yeah that would actually work, thanks, last-resort solution #2!

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that the visible location on the page is the same, that could be a relatively quick solution:

```
function compareByVisibleLocation(a, b) {
  if (a.offsetTop > b.offsetTop) {
    return 1;
  } else if (a.offsetTop < b.offsetTop) {
    return -1;
  }

  if (a.offsetLeft > b.offsetLeft) {
    return 1;
  } else if (a.offsetLeft < b.offsetLeft) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

nodes.sort(compareByVisibleLocation);
```

Else, you can use `querySelectorAll()` to quickly build an index (it's a depth-first pre-order traversal) either by explicitly marking the nodes you want to index with an `indexed-node` classname.

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.indexed-node');
```

Or by grabbing all of a single node type, if that's works:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('div');
```

Or by just grabbing all nodes:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('*');
```

And then adding an index attribute to each node:

```
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) { nodes[i].__DomIndex = i; }
```

You can sort like this then:

```
var nodes = yourGetMethod().sort(function(a,b) {
  if (a === b) {
    return 0;
  } else if (a.__DomIndex > b.__DomIndex) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
});
```

Should work down to IE8.

Comment: Visual location and DOM order are frequently unrelated. Floats, various positioning, etc., come into it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't disagree, of course. But, if the OP's intention is to populate certain content in the order it appears on-page, this is probably what he needs anyway ...